# Create file inside of zip archive python

Tags: python, zip

I have an external file-system and a way to download data from there. I want to download all data into .zip archive. 
What I can do is:

- Create `file` to write into
- Download `data` from device to this `file`
- Write `file`
- Add file to zip archive with `zipfile.write(file)`

What I want to do is:

- Create zip `archive`
- Download `data` from device to created file in this archive **without** creating it on my local drive

Here is not working code to get an Idea:

```
def get_all_files(self):
    self.savedir()
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(self.dir_to_save+"/SD_contents.zip", 'w');
    for file in self.nsh.get_all_files("/fs/microsd"):
            # get_all_files() returns list of full file paths on the SD
            print file
            data = self.nsh.download_file("/fs/microsd"+file)
            zipf.write(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ZipFile.writestr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) will allow you to write the contents of an in-memory buffer to a zip entry given by filename or `ZipInfo` instance. But there is no way to do it in a streaming manner due to the nature of zip files.

Answer (score 2):

If your target is simply to not create temp file, [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)
 is your saver, along with `ZipFile.writestr()` from Ignacio's answer.